# How to enable `git idiff` to show the indentation correctly

Tags: git

```
$ git config --list | grep idiff
alias.idiff=diff --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w

$ git idiff hello.py
...
+    for x in containers:
+    delete_x(x)


$ git diff hello.py
...
+    for x in containers:
+        delete_x(x)

hello.py
...
    for x in containers:
        delete_x(x)
...
```

I always use the alias `git idiff` to check the code difference. However, I need to figure out how to enable the indentation shown in original code.

Question> Which other parameters I should use to correct the misalignment issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command `git diff --diff-algorithm=patience` to see diff.